# Missing capital in "info" tab of tag page

Tags: bug, capitalization

Very very minor issue, but at some point, a capital "I" went missing in the "info" tab below, whereas all the other tabs are capitalized. Happens on the 4-5 sites I've tested, likely on all others. It has apparently been so since at least [March 5th](https://web.archive.org/web/20190305055629/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug).

> [image: missing capital]

It used to be capitalized, per [this Archive screenshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20190105040914/http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman)<sup>1</sup> (January 5th):

> [image: Previous version had a capital I]

I thought the trend was to go for Title Case as much as possible, so am I right in thinking that was unintended? If not, why is it so?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>And the fact that knowing myself, I'd have twigged earlier if it hadn't been...</sub>